# Worldpay Cybersource Secure acceptance issue when site is hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, worldpay, cybersource

We've been pulling our hair out with this for some time now and are having to resort to asking the community for some assistance...

We've created a simple test application (ASP.Net C# webforms) and a number of Cybersource Secure acceptance profiles and can process payments in the app, but only when it's being debugged in Visual Studio.

As soon as we host the site in IIS, we get a "Session Timed Out" message instantly when we attempt to generate the card details page from Worldpay.

The process works by building some form data, securely signing that form data and posting it to the Worldpay endpoint, when that responds its means to insert a card detail entry document into an. This works in Visual Studio 2022, but not when hosted in IIS.

has anyone else experienced the grey "Session Time out" screen when hosting the CyberSource Worldpay page using Secure Acceptance? If you managed to work out how to fix it, please let me know!

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide detailed error information? By the way, have you tried increasing the session timeout in IIS?

Comment: It turns out this was a third party cookie issue.

Comment: @Karl can you please elaborate on this and if possible provide the solution you used? Thanks.